# Yocto install python application using bdist_wheel

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi, python3, yocto

I am trying to install my custom python3-based application on my raspberry pi CM4 board based on Yocto Kirkstone. As mentioned in the migration notes of kirkstone, distutils method for installing python modules is deprecated. So I am using setuptools3.bbclass.
But I didn't know how to install my application to a custom path using `SETUPTOOLS_BUILD_ARGS`. For `DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS`, I was using the following:

```
DISTUTILS_INSTALL_ARGS = "--root=${D} \
--single-version-externally-managed \
--prefix=/opt/hfas/app/${PN} \
--install-lib=/opt/hfas/app/${PN} \
--install-data=/opt/hfas/app/${PN}/data"
```

Where "/opt/hfas" is my path, where I want to install my application. Could anyone please let me know how I could setup my application?